# Нужен ли здесь вопросительный знак?

Tags: пунктуация, знак

*Жду информацию о количестве сотрудников, и какую поддержку с нашей стороны по приезду и бронированию гостиницы мы могли бы оказать.*

В конце точка или вопросительный знак?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет вопроса. Здесь частично опущена избыточность.

Жду информацию о количестве сотрудников и (о том,) какую поддержку (с нашей стороны) по приезду и бронированию гостиницы мы могли бы оказать.

Answer (score 0):

Образец: **Я думал уж о форме плана и как героя назову.**

Однородные отношения между придаточным изъяснительным и  второстепенным членом предложения, вопросительного знака нет, запятой тоже нет.

**Сообщите информацию о количестве сотрудников и какую поддержку с нашей стороны по приезду и бронированию гостиницы мы могли бы оказать.**

Обычный деловой стиль, содержание понятно.

Comment: Вы не прочитаете ли, что у вас получилось? )))

Comment: Извините, небольшая неточность в редактировании.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можно сделать так: разбить эту бюрократическую фразу на два предложения:
1) Жду информацию о количестве сотрудников.  2) Какую поддержку с нашей стороны по приезду и бронированию гостиницы мы могли бы оказать? (То есть в конце этого второго предложения спокойно ставим знак вопроса...)

Comment: Вы не правите основную проблемы. Косноязычие автора.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к другим ответам.

(1) Не могу смириться с "поддержкой по приезду и бронированию гостиницы ".  Это не деловой стиль, а отсутствие грамотности.

Нормальный стиль: **"помощь в организации приезда и бронировании гостиницы"**

Для отъявленных бюрократов: **"поддержка в вопросе приезда и бронирования гостиницы".**

(2) Плохо сочетается по стилю вежливое предложение помощи ("какую помощь мы могли бы оказать") и требование некоей **информации** по этому поводу. Гораздо лучше сказать: "Сообщите, какую помощь в организации приезда и бронировании гостиницы мы могли бы оказать." А информацию о количестве сотрудников запросить отдельным предложением.

Таким образом, мой вариант:

**Жду информацию о количестве сотрудников. Сообщите, какую помощь в организации приезда и бронировании гостиницы мы могли бы оказать.**

Answer (score 0):

Если вопрос поставлен **прямо**, то надо.
Если же он поставлен **косвенно** (как в вашем примере), то правильнее поставить точку.

Answer (score -1):

Вы соединили повествовательное и вопросительное предложения в одно, ставшее повествовательным. Следовательно, ставится точка.

Вы же ждёт информации о специфике поддержки?

"По приезде" пишется с "е" на конце (предлог *по* в значении *после чего-либо* употребляется с предложным падежом).

"С нашей стороны мы могли бы" - избыточность, плеоназм.

Предложение можно перестроить так:

*Жду информацию о количестве сотрудников; в какой помощи с нашей стороны при бронировании гостиницы могут нуждаться приехавшие?*

---

P. S. Тогда бронирование гостиницы уже входит в варианты помощи, его (бронирование) не надо выделять особым пунктом.

*Жду информацию о количестве сотрудников и какую помощь мы можем оказать в организации их приезда.*

Comment: Здесь информация по приезду (по чему),если уж править, то на "о приезде". Что до точки в конце вопрос спорный.

Comment: Имело ввиду, не когда приедут (т.е. по приезде) сотрудники оказывать поддержку, а для организации "приезда" (т.е. прибытия) сотрудников..

Comment: Норма, тогда "по приезду  и бронированию". Я сейчас добавлю в ответ вариант.

Comment: Да, в письме указала " по бронированию", а здесь опечатка)

Comment: @behemothus, Как бы вы поступили?

Comment: @Норма, я полный ответ написал.

Answer (score -1):

Фраза изначально косноязычна, говорить о правильности пунктуации не приходится.

"С нашей стороны" - лишнее, если есть "мы".
Если информация по "приезду и бронированию" - то в одном падеже извольте.
И без запятой, видимо, после "сотрудников", если это два дополнения. А если это две разные фразы, то их надо и оформлять соответственно.

И прочее.

//---

В отношении точки или вопросительного знака.

В принципе возможно и так и эдак - в зависимости понимания сути. Но поскольку вы соединили в одной фразе несоединимое, то и эта суть не просматривается.

После необходимой переделки - в зависимости от смысла - получится что-то вроде

***Жду информацию о количестве сотрудников и о том, какую поддержку по приезду и бронированию гостиницы мы могли бы оказать.***

Здесь - с точкой. Этот вариант я бы рекомендовал.

Можно перестроить по-другому.
*Жду информацию, о количестве сотрудников и какую поддержку о приезде и бронировании гостиницы мы могли бы оказать?*

**Это хуже**, разговорный вариант, привожу только для демонстрации теоретической возможности сохранения вопросительного знака (хотя и тут он очень условен).

В любом случае нужно какое-то согласование в падежах навести у "приезда" и "бронирования". Иначе конфузы получаются из-за непонимания смысла, "по приезду" воспринимается как ошибочное употребление "по приезде" (= после приезда).

*Пока писал, вопрос с падежами выяснился, но я это увидел уже после.*

Comment: Очередной минус "ниачем".